# Running this groovy jenkins script output this error "WorkflowScript: 17: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 17, column 11"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy

```
#!groovy


env.BEARER_TOKEN = "uuuuuuuuuu"

node {
    publishModule()
}

def publishModule() {
    stage('Deploy Modules') {
  }
} 
def buildPayload() {
    def payload = 
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
          "vcs-repo": {
            "identifier":"nnnnnn",
            "oauth-token-id":"hhhhhh",
            "display_identifier":"nnnnnn"
          }
          "no-code": true
        },
        "type":"registry-modules"
     }
 }
}

def deployModules() {
    def payload = buildPayload()
    def response = httpRequest(
        customHeaders: [
                [ name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer " + env.BEARER_TOKEN],
                [ name: "Authorization", value: "application/vnd.api+json" ]
            ],
        httpMode: 'POST',
        responseBody: "${payload}",
        url: "https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/organizations/my-organization/registry-modules/vcs"

        
    )
}
```

```
WorkflowScript: 17: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 17, column 11.
       "data": {
             ^
```

I am trying to build this code in a Jenkinsfile so I am getting this error.  **WorkflowScript: 17: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 17, column 11.** Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Groovy language docs](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_maps), when defining a map literal, the keys should not be surrounded by double quotes.  I.e.:

```
def payload = {
  data: {
    attributes: {
      some_key: "some_value"
    }
  }
}
```